# maintaining static list of countries for each endpoint in Java Spring

Tags: spring, hashmap, properties-file

Need to maintain a static list of countries for particular property(endpoint) from the properties file.
 How can we maintain the list? 
Should have ENUM defined for static list or load both countries and endpoint from different properties file

Answer (score 1):

In xml configuration define the map and list as below

```
<util:map id="endPtMap">
    <entry key="endPt1">
        <ref bean="countryList1" />
    </entry>
    <entry key="endPt2">
        <ref bean="countryList2" />
    </entry>
</util:map>

<util:list id="countryList1" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>UK</value>
    <value>US</value>
</util:list>

<util:list id="countryList2" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>UK</value>
    <value>AUS</value>
    <value>IN</value>
</util:list>
```

Inject the above map in your class as

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("endPtMap")
private Map<String,List<String>> endPtMap;
```